# How to check for None when returning data

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am fetching my data like this

```
 case class MyClass(s: Option[Safe] = None, t: Option[Threat] = None)

        val myCheck = for {
          t <- fT
          s <- fS
        } yield MyClass(s, t)

        onComplete(myCheck) {
          case Success(check) =>
            check match {
              case (maybeMyClass) =>
                complete(ToResponseMarshallable(maybeMyClass))
            }
```

This works well when my records are found, however, when no records are found I get a `MyClass(None, None)`. I would like to catch that using pattern matting and throw an appropriate message. How can I use pattern matching here to catch when the data is `null`?

Comment: I see that `s` and `t` are of type`Option`. Do you get `None` or `null`?

Comment: what is `fT` and `fS`?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik in the browser i see [null,null]. iam using `ToResponseMarshallable` to show json in the browser. But i wasnt to do pattern matching before the ToResponseMarshallable is even called when there is no data

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh they are futures.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik I printed the output to command line and it is `MyClass(None, None)` so `null` is only shown in the browser. in my code, how can I check for `MyClass(None, None)` ? something like `case(Success(...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dealing with values that might be `null` it is important to wrap them using `Option`. The `Option` object will check for `null` values and return `None`.

However, using `Some` will **not** check for `null` and you can get `Some(null)`.

If you have an option that might be `Some(null)` you can clean it up by wrapping it in `Option` again by using `flatMap(Option(_))`

For example:

```
val s: String = "x"
val n: String = null

Option(s) // Some("x")
Option(n) // None
Some(s)   // Some("x")
Some(n)   // Some(null) <- NB

Some(n).flatMap(Option(_)) // None
```

---

#### Update after comments

From the comments it appears that the `null` is actually in JSON, and is presumably coming from parsing `None` rather than a Scala `null`. In that case you can just check for `None` as usual:

```
check match {
  case MyClass(None, _) =>
    // Error: missing Safe value
  case MyClass(_, None) =>
    // Error: missing Threat value
  case _ =>
    complete(ToResponseMarshallable(check))
}
```

Comment: in my case class i am wrapping them in option

Comment: I printed the output to command line and it is `MyClass(None, None)` so `null` is only shown in the browser. in my code, how can I check for `MyClass(None, None)` ? something like `case(Success(...))`